# Using the Test Runner with Mocha and Zombie

Tags: mocha.js, zombie.js

I would like to run the test runner as well as command line for my Zombie tests. So far what i tried is:

1) One Test

```
var Browser = require('zombie'),
should = require('should'),
browser = new Browser();


describe('Loads pages', function() {

    it('Google.com', function(done) {
        browser.visit('/index.html', function () {
            browser.text('title').should.equal('Hello World');
            done();
        });
    });

});
```

2) This Html Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mocha"><p><a href=".">Index</a></p></div>
  <div id="messages"></div>
  <div id="fixtures"></div>


  <!--Imports -->
  <script src="../node_modules/should/should.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/require.js"></script>
  <script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>

  <!--Tests -->
  <script src="test.js"></script>

  <script>
    onload = function(){
        var runner = mocha.run();
   };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything is fine running mocha from the command line but if i open the browser page I get..

> Error: Module name "zombie" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use
>   require([]) http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

I was looking around for a zombie.js file in the node modules to load but I dont see any thing obvious?
Is there a way to get rid if this error and have this working?

Comment: Zombie, to my knowledge, does not work this way. You would use it within tests run within node itself.

Answer (score 0):

`var Browser = require('zombie'),`

this is nodejs syntax, but you're using this in the context of requirejs in browser. requirejs is complaining that you have to use the amd format to load your module like:
`var Browser = require(['zombie'], function(zombie) { ... });`

BUT this will not work anyway because zombie is build for nodejs (commandline). It tries everything to simulate a browser - so its a little bit to much to actually call it in the browser.

Whats the reason that you want zombie tests to have in the mocha test runner? Seperate your tests into acceptance tests that will be called from commandline (with zombie) and those that are real unit tests (for the browser, without zombie) that will be called with the testrunner.